# Using XAudio2 to Process Microphone Input

Tags: voice, xaudio2

I am trying to come up with a solution to process microphone input for a game. Not entirely sure where to start. I was looking into using XAudio2, but it doesn't seem to have support for microphone processing? Is this correct? What do most companies in the industry currently use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XAudio2 is intended for real-time mixing, source-rate conversion, and DSP effects such as position audio as is commonly used in games. It does not handle audio input which on Windows is typically done with Windows Core Audio (aka WASAPI)--on Windows XP input was part of DirectSound.

You can capture data using WASAPI and then process it using XAudio2 for output.

See the [WindowsAudioSession](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/WindowsAudioSession), [CaptureSharedEventDriven](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/audio/CaptureSharedEventDriven), and [CaptureSharedTimerDriven](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/audio/CaptureSharedTimerDriven) samples

Answer (score 0):

I used OpenAL a while ago, it may fit your needs.

The pro's are the portability and easy setup, you have also access to a good documentation and guide.

Take a look at their website, you can find there everything you will need:
[OpenAL website](https://www.openal.org/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Is it 64bit compatible?

Comment: Yep, I had no issues using it.

Comment: The con is that you need a redist for OpenAL. On Windows 8 or later, XAudio 2.8 is built in the operating system. Note that OpenAL is not supported for UWP apps.